# Quickest way to run python script via apache on Debian (11)

Tags: debian, python, apache-httpd

So recently I wanted to remotely trigger a python script, apache was already installed and Im familiar with it so figured id look into that, another option would be to code a custom socket server in python which is very easy, but then you got to make it a service.

This is not to run at large scale, just inside private network, and can also run sh bash scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are several was to do it such as apache CGI (this method), mod_python or mod_wsgi, of which neither take very long to setup. I found this method to have the least steps.

First step to enable cgi mod *(a2enmod in my case was not in my default path, but was found in /usr/sbin/)*

```
/usr/sbin/a2enmod cgi

systemctl restart apache2
```

**That is it !!** now if you put a .sh or .py script in /usr/lib/cgi-bin folder and make it owner root and execute permission it can be accessed from the web address

```
http://machine_address/cgi-bin/script.py
```

note that you need to have your shebang at the start of your script

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
print("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8")
print ("Content-type:text/html\r\n")
print("<H1> Hello, From python server :) </H1>")
```

**Going Further:**

- You can keep the script somewhere more convenient for editing such as
  your home dir or a repo, and simlink it to /usr/lib/cgi-bin, just chown the group to your user group while keeping the owner root, and set perms to 775
- You can access the submitted query url for GET params with: (after import os)

  ```
  queryString = os.environ.get('QUERY_STRING')
  ```
- Even though the cgi script must be owned by root to run, inside the python script any code is run as user www-data (default apache user). This might be fine, but if you need it as a different user, such as your 'normal' user account, one option (which i looked into) is mod_suexec which allows specifying the user a cgi script runs as. But I found it easier to just change the default user that apache runs as to my main user account. Its quicker/simpler and then I can access the error log files without su to root (to see python errors), and interact with my home files. Set user/grp in:(followed by restart)

  ```
  /etc/apache2/envvars
  ```
- You can customise settings more look in eg cgi path, symlink perms etc.

  ```
   /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/serve-cgi-bin.conf
  ```
- You can have python output errors in pretty html on your page, rather than to apache error.log by adding this to the top of your script:

  ```
  import cgitb
  cgitb.enable()
  ```